# How do I cast into an array of NSObjects?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsobject

Coming from Java, I'm writing:

```
NSObject* obj[] = (NSObject* []) [self getResult];
```

And the compiler complains `Cast to incomplete type 'NSObject *[]'`

What's the proper way to cast an object to an array of objects?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an NSArray or a plain C array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getResult` returns a single objects and what you want is an array of objects, as of Xcode 4.4 you'd probably use:

```
NSArray *objects = @[ [self getResult] ];
```

That'll create an (immutable) array containing exactly one object — whatever the result of `getResult` was.

In Objective-C arrays may contain any object; you don't create arrays to hold objects of a specific type.

Comment: Thanks, immutable arrays are exactly what I needed.

Comment: better retain that puppy the @[ array is autorelease

Comment: @stackmonster well that's just a local variable in my example, but as Eir is coming from Java he's probably using ARC rather than taking the time to learn manual memory management?

Comment: @Tommy I liked the example you gave, since I need a way to "statically" initialize (multidimensional) arrays, and then get a hold of an array object, at any level. I didn't realize there is a "catch" with this construction you suggested, if you can give me a hint, I'm not so lazy to look into manual memory management (but coming from Java, I do consider it - as well as some other objective-c features - a bit primitive; it's powerful allright, but now I'm dealing with an application where performance is not an issue, so manual memory management in this case is a waste of time). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given your admitted newness to the language and libraries: You would generally use a collection type, such as `NSArray`. similarly, `-getResult` would return an `NSArray`.

---

Also note that in ObjC, typecasting is literally passing the `NSObject` type pointer as another type -- there is no implicit promotion (as you would see in Java). If you wanted to downcast an `NSObject` to an `NSArray`, you could use `NSArray * array = (NSArray*)[self getResult];`. Again, there is no promotion -- if the result is an `NSString`, then you are still dealing with an `NSString` at runtime.

Tommy's answer (+1) demonstrates how you would create an `NSArray` which contains one element -- An alternative way to write that, which does not rely on the latest compiler features is `NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self getResult]];`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I accepted Tommy's solution since it also explained to me how can I simply initialize my arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the built in Array classes. Either `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`